# Two Dimensional Python Array Sort: Sort the first having the same second values

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I am currently working on coordinates and somehow, I need to sort the x-coordinates in ascending order having the same y-coordinates without touching the y-coordinates.

Here's the sample input:

```
x = [213,212,213,214,215,216,215,216,217,216,218,217,219,220,219]
y = [352,333,332,330,328,327,327,326,325,325,324,324,323,322,322]
xy = np.array([x,y])
```

Here's the desired output:

```
x = [213,212,213,214,215,215,216,216,216,217,217,218,219,219,220]
y = [352,333,332,330,328,327,327,326,325,325,324,324,323,322,322]
```

Note: I have been searching for this one but I can't seem to find a direct answer. Thank you.

Comment: sort the x list first?

Comment: @Copperfield I'm not sure if sorting the x list first is the same idea because it might change the order of the y list. I only need to sort the x having the same y values without touching the y.

Comment: in your example the x list is independent from the y list, whatever you do the x list have no effect on the y list

Comment: @Copperfield sorry for the wrong example, i somehow updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can first make a list of pair and order that by the first coordinate and them make it into a numpy array

```
>>> x = [213,212,213,214,215,216,215,216,217,216,218,217,219,220,219]
>>> y = [352,333,332,330,328,327,327,326,325,325,324,324,323,322,322]
>>> xy=sorted(zip(x,y),key=lambda pair:pair[0])
>>> xy
[(212, 333), (213, 352), (213, 332), (214, 330), (215, 328), (215, 327), (216, 327), (216, 326), (216, 325), (217, 325), (217, 324), (218, 324), (219, 323), (219, 322), (220, 322)]
>>> nxy = np.array(xy).T
>>> nxy
array([[212, 213, 213, 214, 215, 215, 216, 216, 216, 217, 217, 218, 219,
        219, 220],
       [333, 352, 332, 330, 328, 327, 327, 326, 325, 325, 324, 324, 323,
        322, 322]])
>>> nxy
array([[212, 213, 213, 214, 215, 215, 216, 216, 216, 217, 217, 218, 219,
        219, 220],
       [333, 352, 332, 330, 328, 327, 327, 326, 325, 325, 324, 324, 323,
        322, 322]])
>>>
```

after some good old trial and error find a way to sort them in numpy

```
>>> x = [0, 500, 100, 300, 200, 800, 400, 600, 700, 900]
>>> y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> xy= np.array([x,y])
>>> xy
array([[  0, 500, 100, 300, 200, 800, 400, 600, 700, 900],
       [  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9]])
>>> np.argsort(xy[0]) #get an array with the index that correspond to the elements in a sorted fashion 
array([0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 1, 7, 8, 5, 9], dtype=int64)
>>> xy[:,np.argsort(xy[0])] #ask for the elements in the aforementioned order, while preserving their pairing
array([[  0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900],
       [  0,   2,   4,   3,   6,   1,   7,   8,   5,   9]])
>>>
```

Comment: Interesting. How does sorting xy[0] sort both rows correspondingly? Where do I look in the documentation for that?

Comment: I suppose it should be somewhere in the [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/), I was testing to see if it worked or not

Comment: Oh wait, I thought I had seen a difference in the second row before and after but I don't see it anymore, so I can't tell whether the second row was touched or not.

Comment: in the second example you can see that the second row wasn't affected by sorting only the first

Comment: Ah, yes. But then I highly doubt that this is what they want. I mean, if they just wanted `x.sort()`, that's so trivial nobody would ask for it.

Comment: @KellyBundy well, is also a new user, so who know...

Comment: Maybe. The whole question is really unclear and weird. Among other issues, they say "having the same y-coordinates without touching the y-coordinates", which sounds like saying the same thing twice. So presumably the two things don't mean the same? But then what do they mean? It's a mystery...

Comment: @Copperfield I already tried that actually but it doesn't work if the input looks like this.
x = [213,212,213,214,215,216,215,216,217,216,218,217,219,220,219]
y = [352,333,332,330,328,327,327,326,325,325,324,324,323,322,322]


so if you are sorting based on x, we have a new (212,352) coordinates which doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. I think they want to group the coordinates by y-value, and in each group, they want to sort by x-value. But in their example, that seems to be the same as simply sorting the x-values (ignoring the x-values).

Comment: @KellyBundy I am really sorry for the bad wording of the problem. Actually, it took me some time to put it into words but it's still confusing how I can organize my thought about the problem. I apologize

Comment: @KellyBundy YES! I just want the y coordinates untouched but the sorting in the x is not the whole but it's based if they only have the same y coordinates.

Comment: oh, I see soo sort by x, but such that the pair (x,y) remain the same, I know how to do that in regular python, in numpy I would need to look it up, I will update with the regular python in a bit...

Comment: @MelonStreams is done, I find a way to do it in numpy too